# Rails find_by_sql with parameters, LIKE %...%

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In Rails I have a query, let's assume it's this:

```
sql    = 'SELECT * FROM answer WHERE name = :name'
params = { name: 'John' }
Answer.find_by_sql([
  sql,
  params
])
```

Now I want to allow for partial-string matching. I tried to do the following in `sql`:

```
"SELECT * FROM answer WHERE name LIKE %:name%"
```

But that results in:

```
"SELECT * FROM answer WHERE name LIKE %'John'%"
```

How would I go about this without exposing the code to Sql injections?

Comment: I am not sure about this, but have you tried this syntax withsingle quotes around  matched string? `"SELECT * FROM answer WHERE name LIKE '%:name%'"`

Comment: Thanks for the response. This unfortunately results in `"SELECT * FROM answer WHERE name LIKE '%'John'%'"`

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm not fully satisfied with it, I found a solution.

```
sql    = 'SELECT * FROM answer WHERE name LIKE :name'
name   = 'John'
params = { name: "%{name}%" }
Answer.find_by_sql([
  sql,
  params
])
```

So I add the `%...%` to the string itself, which is in turn added to the SQL.